Mac partition corrupted, not recognized after deleting Ubuntu in Dual-Boot
The problem has probably been shown uncountable times in this forum, but, as written above, I had a Macbook Pro 2015 13 inches with a dual-boot containing Mac os Monterrey 12.7.5 and Ubuntu 24.02.
Recently I deleted my Ubuntu partiton (40gbs) with Disk-Utility inside Mac os, but, as I restarted my computer, my Mac os partition became corrupted somehow and I couldnt startup Monterrey nor Ubuntu as I deleted it, instead, it shows me GNU grub
Also, theres no Mac in startup
Moreover, if i try to look up what happened to my partition, it seems like it still exist and has information, but became corrupted

And, finally, the partition changed names to FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF

Hope someone knows how can i fix this without erasing my data, if not, i would like to know what happened here and if i can return my mac to a normal state.

Your disk0s2 should be type Apple_APFS.
